# Get a string after a specific word, using a program that has limited regex features?

Tags: regex, regex-group

Looking for help on building a regex that captures a 1-line string after a specific word.

The challenge I'm running into is that the program where I need to build this regex uses a single line format, in other words dot matches new line. So the formula I created isn't working. See more details below. Any advice or tips?

**More specific regex task:**

I'm trying to grab the line that comes after the word Details from entries like below. The goal is pull out 100% Silk, or 100% Velvet. This is the material of the product that always comes after Details.

**Raw data:**

```
<p>Loose fitted blouse green/yellow lily print. 
V-neck opening with a closure string. 
Small tie string on left side of top.</p> 
<h3>Details</h3> <p>100% Silk.</p> 
<p>Made in Portugal.</p> <h3>Fit</h3>
 <p>Model is 5‰Ûª10,‰Û size 2 wearing size 34.</p> <p>Size 34 measurements</p>

    OR

<p>The velvet version of this dress. High waist fit with hook and zipper closure. 
Seams run along edges of pants to create a box-like.</p> 
<h3>Details</h3> <p>100% Velvet.</p> 
<p>Made in the United States.</p> 
<h3>Fit</h3> <p>Model is 5‰Ûª10‰Û, size 2 and wearing size M pants.</p> <p>Size M measurements Length: 37.5"åÊ</p> 
<p>These pants run small. We recommend sizing up.</p>
```

**Here is the current formula I created that's not working:**

Replace (.)(\bDetails\s+(.)) with $3

The output gives the below:

```
<p>100% Silk.</p> 
<p>Made in Portugal.</p> 
<h3>Fit</h3> 
<p>Model is 5‰Ûª10,‰Û size 2 wearing size 34.</p> 
<p>Size 34 measurements</p>

OR

<p>100% Velvet.</p> 
<p>Made in the United States.</p> 
<h3>Fit</h3> <p>Model is 5‰Ûª10‰Û, size 2 and wearing size M pants.</p> <p>Size M measurements Length: 37.5"åÊ</p> 
<p>These pants run small. We recommend sizing up.</p>
```

`

How do I capture just the desired string? Let me know if you have any tips! Thank you!

Comment: Your regex is not giving the output you described. Can you provide an example in regex101.com?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to provide a working solution in your situation as you mention your program has "limited regex features" but don't explain what limitations.

Here is a Regex you can try to work with to capture the target string

```
^(?:<h3>Details<\/h3>)(.*)$
```

Comment: Thank you! I asked around a lot and here's what I found that ended up working. .*<[^>]*>Details<[^>]*>\s<[^>]*>([^<]*)<.*

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use `BeautifulSoup` for something like this, but here are two solutions you could use:

Match the line after "Details", then pull out the data.

```
matches = re.findall('(?<=Details<).*$', text)

matches = [i.strip('<>') for i in matches]

matches = [i.split('<')[0] for i in [j.split('>')[-1] for j in matches]]
```

Replace "Details<...>data" with "Detailsdata", then find the data.

```
text = re.sub('Details<.*?<.*>', '', text)

matches = re.findall('(?<=Details).*?(?=<)', text)
```